# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord BLOB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, blob

Im trying to get some data from database, but its kinda not working.
I use

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")
```

to get BLOB objects, but it only returns the first BLOB. BLOB's contain text strings so it shouldn't be that hard. Other queries works fine.
I have no control about DB Schema, so I cant chose how the data is stored.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

The queries is just standart SQL queries. The one for blob is:

```
select data from measure_data where measure_id = 'some int here' AND snapshot_id = 'some int here'
```

Data is the column name where BLOB lives. The same query executed in MySQL Workbench produces the correct result.
Its bit tricky to write the queries now, because Im already at home.

But since the same SQL produces correct result in Workbench then I suppose the problem is with Ruby.

Comment: can u please write the sql query for blob and the other queries that work?

Comment: How do you read the results from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")`.